# For some reason, this object is not acknowledged as existing when put into the thread below

Tags: java

I am a beginning programmer and right now I am simply attempting to create a program in which I can make a character move around on a screen with my keys.  Most of the other stuff I have written has been tested but I can't get this to compile because of one simple error.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TryGUI
{

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Gladiator red = new Gladiator(200, 200);
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
      {
         public void run() 
         {
            CreateAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }

   private static void CreateAndShowGUI()
   {
      JFrame newGUI = new JFrame("New");
      newGUI.pack();
      newGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      newGUI.getContentPane().add(new ManageGladiator());
      //newGUI.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      newGUI.setVisible(true);
      red.repaint();

   }

}
```

For some reason, when the program reaches red.repaint, I get this error:

```
TryGUI.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
      red.repaint();
      ^
  symbol:   variable red
  location: class TryGUI
1 error
```

I do not understand why the object is not recognized as existing as it is called earlier on in the program.

Comment: how variable red from `main` should appear in another method? these methods are independent ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading into Variable Scope. A variable is only usable within its scope, and accessing it from outside of its scope will throw an error. This allows you to re-use variable names in different instances, such as using the variable "i" as an iterator for many loops, or create several functions that use a variable "tmp". Otherwise, when you get to several hundred to several thousand (or more) lines of code, your variable names will become ridiculous like "the_iterator_for_loop_in_class_foo"

Here's a tutorial: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  I need to pass the variable there before I can use it there.

Comment: Another option, if you need access to the variable in many class methods, you can make define it as a member of the class. Rather than passing the variable back and forth between methods you could then access the class member from within each method instead.